# R: Read keyboard answers from Telegram Bot

Tags: r, telegram-bot, r-telegram-bot

While using R's `telegram.bot` package, I can't figure out how to read the answer that the user gives from a keyboard. Here it is an minimal sample code:

```
library(telegram.bot)

updater <- Updater(token = Sys.getenv('TOKEN'))
dispatcher <- updater$dispatcher

start_keyboard <- ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
  keyboard = list(
    list(KeyboardButton('Choice_1')),
    list(KeyboardButton('Choice_2'))
  ),
  one_time_keyboard = TRUE
)

start <- function(bot, update) {
  bot$sendMessage(chat_id = update$message$chat_id,
                  text = "Hello!",
                  reply_markup = start_keyboard
  )
}

dispatcher$add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

updater$start_polling()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` answers are sent as plain text by the user, so you can build a text handler for that case:

```
start_handler <- function(bot, update){
  text <- "foo"
  if (update$message$text == "Choice_1"){
    text <- "Response 1"
  }else if (update$message$text == "Choice_2"){
    text <- "Response 2"
  }
  bot$sendMessage(chat_id = update$message$chat_id, text = text)
}

dispatcher$add_handler(MessageHandler(start_handler, MessageFilters$text))

updater$start_polling()
```

**Note:** in case you use an `InlineKeyboardMarkup`, the answer would no longer be text and you should process it through `answerCallbackQuery`, you could do it with the specific `CallbackQueryHandler`.